# .tag returning Nothing when I modify SQL Query in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm attributing some Pictureboxes a .tag value from a dataset.

This works perfectly using my main SQL query. When I add a different query to run on when a value is changed somewhere, the .tag returns Nothing. Bear in mind I have the exact same number of columns the only thing different is I'm filtering for a for a name that will reduce the number of rows from 40 to 6.

Code below:

```
        If Form10.ComboBox1.Text = "Rock" Then
        Me.Sheet1TableAdapter.FillBy1(Me.Contract_ManagementDataSet2.Sheet1)

    End If
```

This called the secondary query if combobox.text is "Rock"

```
  For Each PictSlas In Arr_PicSlAch
        For Each PictCom In Arr_PicCom


            Select Case PictSlas.Tag Or PictCom.Tag 
                Case > 4
                    PictSlas.BackColor = Color.Green
                    PictCom.BackColor = Color.Green


                Case > 3
                    PictSlas.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
                    PictCom.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow

                Case > 2
                    PictSlas.BackColor = Color.Gold
                    PictCom.BackColor = Color.Gold

                Case > 1
                    PictSlas.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
                    PictCom.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange

                Case > 0
                    PictSlas.BackColor = Color.Red
                    PictCom.BackColor = Color.Red

                Case 0
                    PictSlas.Visible = False
                    PictCom.Visible = False


            End Select
```

The previous piece of code acts on the tag attributed to each picture by the SQL query. I have an array for the pictureboxes and a variable that fills them with the data from the datasource by order.

This all works when I use my initial SQL query:

```
SELECT        ID, Vendor, [SLA Achievement] + Commercial + [Operation Stability] + [Cont Improvement] + Partnering AS [Overall Status], [Contract Expiry Date], [SLA Achievement], Commercial, [Operation Stability], 
                     [Cont Improvement], Contract, Partnering
```

FROM            Sheet1

But when I change my query to the following query it stops working and all the tags return Nothing or Null:

```
    SELECT        ID, Vendor, [SLA Achievement] + Commercial + [Operation Stability] + [Cont Improvement] + Partnering AS [Overall Status], [Contract Expiry Date], [SLA Achievement], Commercial, [Operation Stability], 
                         [Cont Improvement], Contract, Partnering
FROM            Sheet1
WHERE        (Vendor = 'Rock')
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem caused by number of rows on my query didn't match the number of objects on the form I was trying to fill.

Added:

```
Try
Catch ex as Exception
End Try
```

On the loop that spins through all the objects and fills them and it now bypasses the error.

Might not be the most clean solution but it sorted my problem.